# Running .net exe file using task scheduler issue

Tags: c#

I have a C# program that I need to run on a scheduled basis. The program will initially load the web browser control and do some task. I have tried running the program by itself and it works well. But it will not run when called by a task scheduler job. This is my only scheduled task that requires a GUI to run. Is there a workaround to do this?

Comment: In Task Scheduler, are you configuring the application to run under your user name? And are you logged on when the task is due to run? I don't think GUI applications can run when there is no Desktop for the user they are running as.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939548/a-workaround-for-the-fact-that-a-scheduled-task-in-windows-requires-a-user-to-be

Comment: The application is run under an administrator account and I enable the option run even if the user is not logged on. This is the same account I use to remote to the server.

Answer (score 0):

For you to do this you have to set up the task scheduler to "Run Only When User is logged on"

See picture:

[[image: click to see image]]1[]

More details on [my blog](http://softvernow.com/2018/04/29/taskschedule/) on how to do this.