# How to detect after system boot if the service is running, if running then start my apps?

Tags: windows, vbscript

In VBScript is it possible to query a specific service name if it's started or running? if its running then execute finally my application. So here is how the flow i am trying to prepare:

1. System is booted
2. Windows 8.1 Startup script is executed (VBS)
3. VBScript now wait and keep checking if the service name "NGINX" started or running already.

   1. If RUNNING, then execute `notepad.exe`.
   2. If not RUNNING, then start the service "NGINX" and make sure its now "RUNNING". if now "RUNNING" then finally execute `notepad.exe`.

Is this possible with VBScript?

Example: this line 6 should be only executed if the service NGINX is running otherwise it should never execute that.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws
set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Dim a
a = "C:\Program Files (x86)\abcd\kiosk.jar"
ws.run "java.exe -cp " & chr(34) & a & chr(34) & " kiosk", 0, False
```

Comment: [Check to See if a Service is Installed and Running](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/01fcf945-ad73-44e0-8cb5-152432bc6bcf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want nginx automatically started after system boot you should [install it as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875396/1630171). You can use a WMI query against the [`Win32_Service`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class to check if a service is running, and also start it in case it isn't:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts.//./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = 'nginx' AND State <> 'Running'"
For Each svc In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  svc.StartService
Next
```

To just check if the service is running and run some other program if it is you could do something like this:

```
isRunning = False
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = 'nginx' AND State = 'Running'"
For Each svc In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  isRunning = True
Next

If isRunning Then
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "notepad.exe", 0
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to install it as a service.  Use a scheduled task to launch it at start up, login, or whatever.
I like the WMI method and that would be what I'd want but you could also execute Net Start, read each line of output, then use If Instr to check for your service name.  If it comes back True then your service is started.  If not, then it hasn't.  Nice thing is that you'd already have your connection created to your Wscript.shell so it would be a simple matter to use Net Start again to start the service.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/507798/Differences-between-Run-and-Exec-VBScript