# Run a ruby exe file as windows service leads to error

Tags: ruby, windows, windows-services

I am stuck on this problem for days, any help will be really appreciated.

Have a ruby file called `app.exe` which is located in `"C:\MyApp\app.exe"`. This is a windows app which creates a system tray icon. When I click on `app.exe` directly this works fine. But I would like to make this as a windows service so that it is on the system tray all the time (after system boot to all users).

So I learnt that `sc` command in windows has some command line arguments which can be used to create a service. I am doing this :

`sc create "testservice" binpath= "C:\Prevas\MyApp\app.exe" displayname= "Test Service`"

And when I start :

```
sc start "testservice"
```

When I do this I get an errror :

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Not able to understand the reason why I am seeing this error, as I am able to kick start the app directly. Any parameters I am missing or anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks guys

Comment: [SC won't do the trick by itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061191/how-to-add-nginx-exe-as-windows-system-service-like-apache/12964345#12964345); you need a service wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163497/running-a-ruby-program-as-a-windows-service).

 Check out [Win32Utils - Ruby library for MS Windows](http://win32utils.rubyforge.org/).

From the doc,

> *Note that some libraries, such as win32-api and win32-service, have*
>   *gems that contain prebuilt binaries so no compiler is necessary for*
>   *those libraries. Just install them as you would any other gem.*

There are some nice wrappers for these Utils. [win32-service](https://github.com/djberg96/win32-service) is one such gem will help you to acheive that.

Go through these [Create a Windows Service with Ruby Part 1](http://abstractcoder.com/2013/07/18/create-a-windows-service-with-ruby-part-1.html) , [Part 2](http://abstractcoder.com/2013/08/02/create-a-windows-service-with-ruby-part-2.html) articles by Steve Johnson.