# Why don't some programs appear on the task manager startup tab?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Many applications start at startup, however, some of them do not appear on the task manager startup tab. What is that due to?
Is there any way to do this with a program, for example, spotify?
What do I need to do in order for a program to start at startup, but not showing in the startup applications tab?
Setting it in HKCU/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run doesn't seem to work, as it starts, but still shows on the mentioned tab. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe it is running in the background with a different name!

Comment: @MobinF.R.G I don't think so, as there are much more programs and processes running than the ones that appear in the startup tab. But thank you anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its mostly a factor of how the program itself is written.  If its written to run as a service, or as a [System Tray application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/how-can-i-make-a-net-windows-forms-application-that-only-runs-in-the-system-tra), or otherwise.

I know there are wrappers for running any exe as a service [NSSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061191/add-nginx-exe-as-windows-system-service-like-apache/21869387#21869387) being the main one I have experience with (but this is mostly for when there is going to be NO user interaction)

I do not know if there is anything that can allow an application to run in the system tray only, not in the taskbar, if it doesn't support it.

But since Spotify does support running minimized to the tray, it does seem like there are some ways to "start spotify minimized", Spotify or other applications might have command line options or other settings to tell them to start "hidden"