# Running selenium automation tests on remote teamcity build agent

Tags: java, selenium, ant, junit, teamcity

Recently we started using Teamcity for build management and to run selenium junit tests using ANT scripts. The tests are running successfully and shown as passed on teamcity console. 
When the tests are running if I login to the build agent machine, I was expecting to be able to see the browser window open and fields getting populated and submitted.  I don't see the Firefox browser window open, wondering how my tests are passing. When I run the same test scripts in Eclipse, the Firefox browser window is opened and the web page fields get populated.

Appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because TeamCity build agents are run as a Windows service. So you won't be able to see the actual GUI.

If you want to change it, please change your build agent installation.

- [Installing and Configuring the TeamCity Server](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server)
- [How can I run a Windows GUI application on as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53232/1177636)
- [Selenium Tests run in the background when TeamCity CI is run as a Windows service](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/5212)
- [Running Automated GUI tests with TeamCity](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5242725)